# Cache problems in Django/PyMongo/MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I have a little Django app that uses PyMongo and MongoDB.
If I write (or update) something in the database, I have to restart the server for it to show in the web page. I'm running with 'python manage.py runserver'
I switched to the django dummy cache but that didn't help.
Every database action is within an 'with MongoClient' statement.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I read in the data in the django_tables2 class variables. So it was never refreshed...

Bangs forehead on desk...